# MYSQL Syntax Assistance

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this query please?
Whichever way i try i continue to get errors

```
SELECT b.SOLD_TO
     , b.CUSTOMER
     , b.JANUARY_BUDGET
     , Round(sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000,2) AS MONTHLY_DESPATCH
     , if(sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000=0 AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET=0,"DOUBLE_ZERO",
if(sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000>0 AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET=0,"NO_BUDGET_GOOD_SHIPMENT",
if(sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000>0 AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET>0 AND (sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000> b.JANUARY_BUDGET,"ABOVE_BUDGET",
if(sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000>0 AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET>0 AND (sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000< b.JANUARY_BUDGET,"POOR_RESULT")))) AS PERFORMANCE
FROM budget2021 b
left JOIN despatches2021 d on d.SOLD_TO = b.SOLD_TO
WHERE b.SOLD_TO=69946 AND d.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN 20210101 and 20210131
GROUP BY b.SOLD_TO
     , b.CUSTOMER
     , b.JANUARY_BUDGET
```

Comment: Just wait until you learn about table aliases. They will blow your mind :-) . And know that `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x =...` is tha same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean by `LEFT JOIN` is the same as `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  What type of field is `INVOICE_DATE`?  `20210101` is not a date, that's an int (`20,210,101` or 20 million 210 thousand 101).

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))) AS PERFORMANCE
FROM budget2021
left JOIN despatches2021  on despatches2021' at line 5

Comment: @rockethazmat exactly as written (but with 'the' instead of 'tha')

Comment: the date is ok, i use a php variable when running properly and the query was working fine before i added the if statements

Comment: @MarkLocke You have quite a lot of `IF`s in there.  Double check all your `(` and `)` and `,`, maybe you're missing one.

Comment: @MarkLocke Check around the `"ABOVE_BUDGET"` part of your query.  I think you're missing a `)` or have a `,` where it shouldn't be.  You have `AND (sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000> b.JANUARY_BUDGET,"ABOVE_BUDGET",`.  This seems to be the issue.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: This `IF()` block is very complicated, consider getting the data and using PHP to make these calculations.  Or, I suggest re-writing this `IF` block, making sure you have all your `,`, `)`, and `(` in line.

Comment: @RocketHazmat good advice, thanks. I took the data into php and manipulated it into 4 queries based on the data mysql sent to it. Stupid why i didnt think of this before, a far easier solution ! thanks again

Comment: Remove all those `/1000`. If a number divided by 1000 is positive so is the number itself.

Comment: Please explain "no matter which way I try" and also "I get errors."  What errors, exactly?  What have you tried?

Comment: To start off with, there is no closing parenthesis for this, and then it goes downhill from there:  if(sum(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT)/1000=0 AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET=0,"DOUBLE_ZERO"

Comment: Switch to a CASE statement, then simplify the cases because they will be handled in order.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, to diffult to explain, what you made wron a

An IF( condition,true,false) is the form independent of how many you nested.

A godd code indentation helps to handle such things

I also had to add  a  NULL at the end of the last IF as i don't knpw really where you want to go with this

```
SELECT 
    b.SOLD_TO,
    b.CUSTOMER,
    b.JANUARY_BUDGET,
    ROUND(SUM(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT) / 1000, 2) AS MONTHLY_DESPATCH,
    IF(SUM(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT) / 1000 = 0
            AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET = 0,
        'DOUBLE_ZERO',
        IF(SUM(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT) / 1000 > 0
                AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET = 0,
            'NO_BUDGET_GOOD_SHIPMENT',
            IF(SUM(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT) / 1000 > 0
                    AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET > 0
                    AND (SUM(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT) / 1000 > b.JANUARY_BUDGET),
                'ABOVE_BUDGET',
                IF(SUM(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT) / 1000 > 0
                        AND b.JANUARY_BUDGET > 0
                        AND (SUM(d.TOTAL_WEIGHT) / 1000 < b.JANUARY_BUDGET),
                    'POOR_RESULT',
                    NULL)))) AS PERFORMANCE   -- here i added the NULL
FROM
    budget2021 b
        LEFT JOIN
    despatches2021 d ON d.SOLD_TO = b.SOLD_TO
WHERE
    b.SOLD_TO = 69946
        AND d.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN 20210101 AND 20210131
GROUP BY b.SOLD_TO , b.CUSTOMER , b.JANUARY_BUDGET
```

Comment: Amazing work! it works for every combination. The 'double zero produces no record but i can use it as a "null"
thanks very much

Comment: thanks to everyone, i am blown away by the help (and expertise) on this forum, thanks to everyone that contributed

Comment: That LEFT JOIN still ain't doing much though